# Reformulation to LMI constraints (H2 Feedforward Control)

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality

I am trying to solve a problem similar to a H2 feedforward control synthesis problem with an additional constraint. I was wondering if it is possible to reformulate the problem to be a set of linear matrix inequalities (LMI) through some combination of transformations and slack variables. Constraints 1-3 and 4-5 can be written separately as LMIs, but I am having difficulty combining the constraints. Dealing with the relationship of $Q A_{aug}$ in constraint (3) and $A_fR$ and $PA_f$ in constraints (4) and (5) is what is giving me the most trouble. The problem is as follows:

Given matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^n, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}, C \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times n}$, and $\delta$ which is an arbitrarily small number.

Find matrices $A_f \in \mathbb{R}^{n_c}, B_f \in \mathbb{R}^{n_c \times m}, C_f \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times n_c},Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n+n_c},W \in \mathbb{R}^p, P \in \mathbb{R}^{n_c}$, and $R \in \mathbb{R}^{n_c}$ such that the following optimization problem is satisfied.

$$\begin{align}
\text{minmize}  \quad &\mu \\
\text{s.t.} \quad  &trace(W)<\mu \tag{1}\\
&\begin{bmatrix}W&C_{aug}\\ C_{aug}^T&Q\end{bmatrix} \succ 0 \tag{2}\\
&\begin{bmatrix}Q&QA_{aug}&QB_{aug}\\ A_{aug}^TQ&Q&0\\ B_{aug}^TQ&0&I\end{bmatrix} \succ 0 \tag{3}\\
&Q \succ 0\\
&W\succ 0\\
&\begin{bmatrix}\delta R&\frac{1}{2}(A_f R- RA_f^T)\\ -\frac{1}{2}(A_f R- RA_f^T)&\delta R\end{bmatrix} \succ 0 \tag{4}\\
&\begin{bmatrix}P& PA_f\\ A_f^T P & P\end{bmatrix} \succ 0 \tag{5}\\
&P \succ 0\\
&R\succ 0\\
\end{align}$$

where $A_{aug} = \begin{bmatrix}A&0\\0&A_f\end{bmatrix}, B_{aug} = \begin{bmatrix}B\\B_f\end{bmatrix},  C_{aug} = \begin{bmatrix}C&-C_f\end{bmatrix}$.

If it helps, (5) corresponds to the eigenvalues of $A_f$ being inside the unit circle, (4) corresponds to the eigenvalues of $A_f$ being restricted to the real axis, and (1-3) correspond to minimizing the H2 norm of a parallel connection of the discrete statespace systems ss($A$,$B$,$C$,$0$) and ss($A_f$,$B_f$,$C_f$,$0$). Please let me know if there is anything that is unclear.

Thank You

Comment: You should state clearly and completely what all the matrices are: which are input data and which are optimization (decision) variables.

Comment: Sorry about that, is the edit more clear?

Comment: (3), (4), and (5) are Bilnear Matrix Inequalities (BMI) which are non-convex, and  generally difficult to solve even for a local minimum, let alone global minimum, and difficult to confidently conclude infeasibility. Do you know if the problem is feasible? If so, do you have a feasible solution you can use as a starting value for a (local) BMI solver, such as PENLAB or PENBMI? In principle, you could try so solve to global optimum using YALMIP's BMIBNB, with PENLAB or PENBMI as upper solver, and Mosek/other LMI solver as lower solver, but chances of success are low, even with. low dimension.

Comment: The problem is feasible, and I do have a solution I can use, but I would like to avoid trying to solve BMIs directly. I was hoping it would be possible to manipulate the constraints either using some combination of transformations or slack variables into a set of LMIs. I do know constraints 1,2,3 can be written as LMI's as shown [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0888327009001307) for the continuous case (equation 13), and (4) and (5) can be combined to an LMI as shown [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S147466701538109X) in section 4.1.

Comment: I don't have access to the paper in the 1st link. The 2nd link's (15) is the same as your (5), if your $A_f$ is the paper's $A$. If both $A_f (A)$ and $P$ are optimization variables, that is a BMI. If one of them is input, it's an LMI. That's why I asked you to clearly state what is input and what are optimization variables.